# bandcamp embed field

Tags: entities, media

I'm running D8.
I need to have a field to embed a bandcamp player in. I'm using media module but there doesn't seem to be a way to embed platforms not officially supported by fx media video, media audio etc.
I'm not a php-coder, just html / css.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a feature request for a contrib module and needs to be submitted to the issue queue on Drupal.org.

Answer (score 2):

If bandcamp offers a method of embedding their players into other websites, you can open a request in the issue queue for the [URL To Video Filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_to_video_filter) (which I'm the developer of), with a link to their embed method, and I'll try to integrate it for you.

Comment: That's awesome. But does your module also support fields? Looks like it's a wysiwyg-thing to me?

Comment: It's not a WYSIWYG, it's an input format, which can be applied to any text filter, and text filters are applied to any fields that are of formatted text. So yes, it works with fields.